# Javascript 'var variable' inside loop vs outside. Any difference in performence

Tags: javascript, var

```
for(var i=0;i<lines.length;i++) {
  var line = lines[i];
```

vs

```
var line;
for(var i=0;i<lines.length;i++) {
  line = lines[i];
```

Do this two snippets have different performance. If yes, please explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run a benchmark on this and have found that there is pretty much no difference in performance.

If you would like to recreate it:

```
var lines = new Array(#BIG_NUMBER#);

lines.fill(#BIG_OBJECT#);

var a = (new Date()).getTime();

for(var i=0;i<lines.length;i++) {
  var line = lines[i]; }

var b = (new Date()).getTime();

var line;
for(var i=0;i<lines.length;i++) {
  line = lines[i]; }

var c = (new Date()).getTime();
console.log("a:" + (b-a) + " b:" + (c-b));
```

This makes sense, as there is almost no difference, both cases will create a local object that will be stored, and will be reassigning it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work differently in both the cases.

In the first one `line` is a ***global variable*** an will be accessible outside the **for loop**, which is not the case in second one.

*So I don't think performance comparison makes any sense here!*

Even then, declaring a variable again and again is unnecessary though I don't think it is a complex operation. But yes declaring it repetitively will deteriorate the performance.

Comment: In the second one the variable also be global and accesible outside of for loop. In javascript there are no block scope only function scope.

Comment: @jcubic there is block level scope in ES6.

Comment: OP ask about `var` not `let`.

Comment: Even if you _were_ right, you've got your examples mixed up.